# How to properly use databases in development?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, development-environment, prisma

I'm struggling with finding out how to properly test stuff on my local PC and then transfer that over to production.
So here is my situation:

I got a project in NodeJS/typescript, and I'm using Prisma in it for managing my database. On my server I just run a MySQL database, and for testing on my PC I always just used SQLite.

But now that I want to use Prisma Migrate  (because it's highly recommended to do so in production) I can't because I use different databases on my PC vs on my Server. Now here comes my question, **what is the **correct way** to test with a database during development?**

Should I just connect to my server and make a test database there? Use VS Code's SSH coding function to code directly on the server and connect to the database? Install MySQL on my PC? Like, **what's the correct way to do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use the **same brand and same version** database in development and testing that you will eventually deploy to. There are compatibility differences between brands, i.e. an SQL query that works on SQLite does not necessarily work the same on MySQL, and vice-versa. Even data types and schema definitions aren't all the same between different SQL products.

If you use different SQL databases in development and production, you will waste a bunch of time and increase your gray hair debugging problems in production, as you insist, "it works on my machine."

This is avoidable!

When I develop on my local computer, I usually have an instance of MySQL Server running in a Docker container on my laptop.

I assume any test data on my laptop is temporary. I can easily recreate schema and data at any time, using scripts that are checked into my source control repo, so I don't worry about losing any data. In fact, I feel no hesitation to drop it and recreate it several times a week.

So if I need to upgrade the local database version to match an upgrade on production, I just delete the Docker container and its data, pull the new Docker image version, initialize a new data dir, and reload my test data again.

Every step is scripted, even the Docker pull.

The caveat to my practice is that you can't necessarily duplicate the software if you use cloud databases, for example Amazon Aurora. There's no way to run an Aurora-compatible instance on your laptop (and don't believe the salespeople that Aurora is fully compatible with MySQL; it's not). So you could run a small Aurora instance in a development VPC and connect to that from your app development environment. At least if your internet connection is reliable enough.

---

By the way, a similar rule applies to all the other technology you use in development. The version of Node.js, Prisma, other NPM dependencies, http and cache servers, etc. Even the operating system might be the source of compatibility issues, but you may have to develop in a Virtual Machine to match the OS to production exactly.

At one past job, I did help the developer team create what we called the "golden image" which was a pre-configured VM with all our software dependencies installed, and we used this golden image for both the developer sandbox VM, and also an AMI from which we launched the production Amazon EC2 instances. So all the developers were guaranteed to have a test environment that matched production exactly. After that, if they had code problems, they could fix it in development and have a much higher confidence it would work after deploying to production.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, sadly not familiar with docker, never really went ahead to learn it, maybe I should now.  Either that or I actually try VSCode's SSH function because that could work too.

Comment: Docker is optional. I just find it makes it quicker to update and reinitialize a MySQL instance on demand. You can run MySQL on a laptop without using Docker. There are lots of instructions and free downloads: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/ Double-check that you're downloading the same version you use in production. To check, run the following SQL query against your production instance: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Thank you,it's well explained. I just wonder if we should execute 'SHOW PLUGINS' as well ?

Comment: That's a good point. If you have any specific non-default configuration or plugins in the production MySQL instance, then you should do your best to apply the same options on your local instance. Of course not the buffer pool size, because it's probably much larger than you can have on your laptop.